# Add Computer To Domain

Tags: networking, domain, windows-domain, windows-server

On a very new Windows Server 2012 R2 setup, I used to be able to browse to a hosted application that runs on the server from my other computer on the same home network. Now I've set it up on a domain (`MYDOMAIN.COM` for example) following [these instructions](http://www.slideshare.net/lravikumarvsp/step-by-step-guide-for-setting-up-windows-server-2012-domain-controller#). Since I've done this, I'm unable to access it. My initial guess is that this is due to my computer not being on `MYDOMAIN.COM`. When I try to point it to that domain in the `Computer Name / Domain Changes` property window, it says the domain could not be found or contacted. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your clients network setting pointing to the new DNS/DHCP/ad?

Comment: How can I check this? I'm sure I can check on my local machine, but I'm not sure how to look at / set this on Server 2012.

Comment: well, your clients network settings... set your preferred dns server . It should point to your new ad/dns/dhcp 2012 server ip address. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7  its probably still pointing to your old router/switch dhcp

Comment: So all I need to do is set my client preferred DNS to my server's IP address?

Comment: Something interesting I've noticed. Despite not being able to see the actual application (Team Foundation Server), I'm able to browse to my server's IP address in my browser and get the IIS welcome screen. I'm not able to access any directory within, however.

Comment: yes, set the dns

Comment: I've done this and I'm going to reboot now as it hasn't worked yet without rebooting.

Comment: So it looks like changing to the domain allowed me to recognize the domain as it is, but I still can't access the /tfs/ directory. If I'm on the server itself, and I browse to localhost/tfs/, I can access it.

Comment: While this problem is technically solved as I was now able to add myself to the domain, I still can't access TFS. I'm wondering if this is now a TFS setup issue. Is that still Super User content?

Comment: You need to setup a share on the folder, and give yourself access to it. Search for it... there are hundreds of links showing you how.